# AES encryption/decryption using EquivalentInverseCipher in C

Tags: c, aes, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'm doing project in AES. Has anyone worked in equivalent inverse cipher? I am researching the underlying concept in it and how to implement in C.

Comment: This can be closed as unclear to too broad.

Answer (score -1):

By Equivalent Inverse cipher are you referring to the new operations supplied by the ? i.e.
[Intel AES-NI (new instruction) library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-instructions-aes-ni/)?

I believe it is possible to integrate this with OpenSSL - as per [these instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/boosting-openssl-aes-encryption-with-intel-ipp/).

The OpenSSL C library is good, but sadly not so well documented. Others have asked before how to [use it for AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132939/c-c-how-to-do-aes-decryption-using-openssl).

Comment: No I'm not refering to INTEL AES_NI....i just want to implement as prescribed in the FIPS PUB 197...Please if you have worked on it do help me out.....It's very urgent..